# Are there results that relate the restriction of the heat semigroup in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the semigroup in a domain?

Tags: parabolic-pde, semigroups-of-operators, heat-equation

I'm thinking about the following situation:0 suppose that
$$
S_{\Omega}(t)f = \int_{\Omega} K_{\Omega}(x,y,t)f(y)dy
$$ where $K_\Omega(x,y ,t)$ is the Dirichlet heat kernel in the domain $\Omega$.
 It is well known that
$$
K_{\Omega}(x,y,t) \leq K_{\mathbb{R}^n} (x,y,t)\quad \forall x,y \in \Omega, t > 0,
$$
so in general
$$(f\ge0)\Longrightarrow\left(
S_{\Omega}(t)f \leq S_{\mathbb{R}^n}(t)\tilde{f}\right),
$$ where $\tilde{f}$ is defined as $f$ in $\Omega$ and $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus \Omega$ ($\tilde{f}$ is the zero extension of $f$).

**Questions**. I'm wondering if equality is possible in some situation, i.e. could it happen that $$
S_{\Omega}(t)f = S_{\mathbb{R}^n}(t)\tilde{f}
$$ for a domain $\Omega\subsetneq \Bbb R^n$?
 Are there any papers, results about it?

Comment: If the complement of $\Omega$ is sufficiently small in a certain sense, then the Dirchlet heat semigroup on $\Omega$ coincides with the heat semigroup on the whole space. Their keyword to look for is the *capacity* of the complement of $\Omega$ (but I don*t know this part of the theory well, so a only write this is a comment rather than a detailed answer).

Comment: But do you know any book, paper that talks about it?

Comment: See for instance Corollary 3.9 in the paper ["Does diffusion determine the body?"](https://zbmath.org/1099.35164) (2002) by Arendt.